# Replacing a path(with special-characters) using a linux sed command

Tags: shell

I have a path inside a script file that goes like
`export DATABASE_XML=/mnt/nfs/reg_work/work_dir/dexter/DUMP/REX-9999/Test_Database.xml`

I need to replace the line say `/mnt/nfs/reg_work/work_dir/dexter/DUMP/REX-9999` with another text say
`$(dirname $(pwd -P))`

so that the line looks like..

`export DATABASE_XML=$(dirname $(pwd -P))/Test_Database.xml`

Tried somethings with sed but i am stuck....
Any help will be appreciated....

Comment: Are you just doing this once on one script? If so, why do you need `sed`?

Comment: Nope i have thousands of scripts that run one by one so i need to make the changes to each of them...

Comment: You say you tried something with `sed`, then you should show what you've tried. Also, there needs to be a little more explanation here. If you have thousands of scripts, do the `DATABASE_XML` strings vary in any particular way? Do the each, for instance potentially have a different base file name assigned, or do they all look just like you show with `Test_Database.xml` as the base file name?

Comment: These Test_Database.xml file is only a pointer to the 8 databases i use.So say there are 8 folders and each folder has the xml file which points to one database....in short i am saying that the path is same in all the scripts so can you help me on how to escape these special characters in sed?

Comment: I mean points in case you misunderstood pointer

Comment: `sed "s/DATABASE_XML=.*\/\([^/]*\)$/DATABASE_XML=\$(dirname \$(pwd -P))\/\1/"`

Comment: great it's working can you please help me understand this??

Comment: why not just `$(dirname $(pwd -P))/$(basename "$DATABSE_XML")` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk that pre-supposes that `DATABASE_XML` is previously set to the path that the OP wants to replace. The result of that would be `DATABASE_XML=$(dirname $(pwd -P))/$(basename "$DATABSE_XML")` which is a circular definition otherwise.

Comment: You mean `DATABASE_XML='$(dirname $(pwd -P))'/$(basename "$DATABSE_XML")` wouldn't work? What is a "circular definition" in bash? There only circular name references I could find.

Comment: @KamilCuk correct, it won't work unless `DATABASE_XML` is already defined. You're defining `DATABASE_XML` in terms of `DATABASE_XML`. Initially, `DATABASE_XML` is undefined, so you'd probably get an error since you'd be executing `basename` on a blank value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the documentation on the `sed` regex to find out about the various constructs for matching strings.

Here's one way to process your scripts:

```
sed "s/DATABASE_XML=.*\/\([^/]*\)$/DATABASE_XML=\$(dirname \$(pwd -P))\/\1/"
```

First, let's have a look at the matching regex:

```
DATABASE_XML=.*\/\([^/]*\)$
```

The `.*` will match zero or more (`*`) of any character (`.`) after `DATABASE_XML=` up until it finds a slash (`\/`, escaped since `/` is being used as the search/replace delimiter), and zero or more (`*`) of a non-`/` (`[^/]`, which defines a group of characters using `[` and `]`, and the `^` means "not", with the only group member being `/`). So `[^/]` is any character except `/` and the `*` means any number of them. We group this with `\(` and `\)` so that we can refer to what is captured here in the replacement string since it represents the file name that we want to keep. Thus, the regex that matches (and captures) the existing file name looks like `\([^/]*\)`.

The replacement string is:

```
DATABASE_XML=\$(dirname \$(pwd -P))\/\1
```

We escape the `$` since they might otherwise be interpreted as special by the shell or `sed`. We want them to simply mean `$` in the replacement. The `\/` is just a slash, again escaped since it is otherwise going to be confused by `sed` as the search/replace delimiter. That leaves the `\1`. The `\1` is replaced by whatever was matched inside the `\(` and `\)` pair of the search regex string, which is the file name in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!! I will go through the sed regex docs for more info..

Comment: what if i want to add one more line to my sed script above: i.e. DATABASE_XML=$(dirname $(pwd -P))/${PWD##*/}

Comment: @MfjoneZ you should write that up as a new question.

Comment: @MfjoneZ no worries. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Use sed to do the substitution. You can choose any character as `s` command separator. Below I use `#`:

```
sed 's#/mnt/nfs/reg_work/work_dir/dexter/DUMP/REX-9999#$(dirname $(pwd -P))#'
```

Example:

```
$ export DATABASE_XML=/mnt/nfs/reg_work/work_dir/dexter/DUMP/REX-9999/Test_Database.xml
$ sed 's#/mnt/nfs/reg_work/work_dir/dexter/DUMP/REX-9999#$(dirname $(pwd -P))#' <<<"$DATABASE_XML"
$(dirname $(pwd -P))/Test_Database.xml
```

You can also choose to expand the command substitutions by not enclosing them inside `'` quotes:

```
$ sed 's#/mnt/nfs/reg_work/work_dir/dexter/DUMP/REX-9999#'"$(dirname $(pwd -P))"'#' <<<"$DATABASE_XML"
/home/Test_Database.xml
```

You can store the path in a variable:

```
$ subst=/mnt/nfs/reg_work/work_dir/dexter/DUMP/REX-9999
$ sed 's#'"$subst"'#'"$(dirname $(pwd -P))"'#' <<<"$DATABASE_XML"
/home/Test_Database.xml
```

The only concern is to use the separator for `sed`'s `s` command such a character, that wouldn't be in the substituted string. If you really need, you can use an unreadable character for the `s` command separator, making the danger minimal (who names their files using `$'\xff'` characters?) Here I use unreadable `0xff` hexadecimal value for `s` command separator:

```
$ sed 's'$'\xff'"$subst"$'\xff'"$(dirname $(pwd -P))"$'\xff' <<<"$DATABASE_XML"
/home/Test_Database.xml
```